# How to form a correct tenant URL for Azure AD

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I have created a tenant in AzureAD.
I have the Directory ID in this format: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
I m using ADAL to communicate with AzureAD

Problem : How to create a correct URL for my tenant in AzureAD?

I must use this :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

Say, this tenant is a paid acct. Do I use above format with ADAL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the directory ID (as you already did) or the tenant name e. g.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com

If you have a verfied domain the URL would look something like this:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.com

However, you need to use the https://login.microsoftonline.com domain since its the IdP that handles the login.

Comment: I think you can basically use any verified domain name instead of the tenant id :)

Comment: @juunas, I don't understand. say, I have my website call. abcxyz.com  Do I need to add or register this website name with AZure AD first so that I can use https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcxyz.com , If I don't register it with Azure AD, I can not use this url format?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the domain to your AAD. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

Comment: Verifying the domain name in AAD allows you to use it for usernames etc.

Comment: @all , Hi all thank for the info. I have a related question to this. with your help, this will make me understand better. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298104/how-to-form-a-correct-tenant-url-for-azure-ad